# using onClick event on button with submit type, instead of using onSubmit event on form element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, validation

`What is the difference between these two?
which one is better and why?

1- using onClick event on button with submit type
2- using onSubmit event on form element
`

Comment: Technically a user does not have to click a button to submit a form. They can hit enter in other fields and it would submit. (Most browsers will trigger that click)